# Finding arc length by approximating

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let's say that a have a smooth curve in 2D and I want to find it's lenght. I split the curve in sections like here: http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section10.03.html.     The only difference is that I want to find the lenght not the area. 
The curve is given by  $r = f(θ)$ , therefore I will say that the arc lenght subtended by a small sector is $f(θ)Δθ$. 
If Δθ is smaller and smaller the sum of these small lenghts will approximate better and better the lenght of the curve. So the lenght should be $$\int_{a}^{b} f(θ) dθ$$
I've tried to compute such an integral for f(x) = 1 - x but it does not work. Where is the mistake?

Comment: f(x) = 1-x is not a function of $\theta$.

Comment: You could write it as a function of θ, r = 1/(sin(θ) + cos(θ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the diagram below, paying special attention to the red triangle.

[image]

The error that you're making is assuming that $rd\theta\approx ds$, when this is, in fact, not the case. $rd\theta$ is a short leg of an obtuse "triangle" (which approaches "rightness" as $d\theta\to 0$). It is $ds$ that approximates the arc length. So the correct arc length should be
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\int^{s(b)}_{s(a)}ds&=& \int^{s(b)}_{s(a)}\sqrt{(ds)^2}\\
&=& \int^b_b\sqrt{(dr)^2 + (rd\theta)^2}\\
&=& \int^b_a \sqrt{\frac{(dr)^2 + (rd\theta)^2}{(d\theta)^2}}d\theta\\
&=& \int^b_a \sqrt{\bigg(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg)^2+r^2}d\theta\\
\end{array}$$
or alternatively
$$L=\int^b_a \sqrt{\bigg(f'(\theta)\bigg)^2+(f(\theta))^2}d\theta\\
$$